# Exception in thread "main" com.twilio.exception.ApiException: api.twilio.com

Tags: twilio-api

```
public static final String ACCOUNT_SID = "ACxxx";
public static final String AUTH_TOKEN = "6xx";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Twilio.init(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);

    Message message =
        Message.creator(new PhoneNumber("+1518xx"), new PhoneNumber("+18xxx"),
                "SMS POC").create();

    System.out.println(message.getSid());
}
```

Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" com.twilio.exception.ApiException: api.twilio.com
    at com.twilio.http.NetworkHttpClient.makeRequest(NetworkHttpClient.java:88)
    at com.twilio.http.HttpClient.reliableRequest(HttpClient.java:38)
    at com.twilio.http.HttpClient.reliableRequest(HttpClient.java:22)
    at com.twilio.http.TwilioRestClient.request(TwilioRestClient.java:42)
    at com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.MessageCreator.create(MessageCreator.java:307)
    at com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.MessageCreator.create(MessageCreator.java:25)
    at com.twilio.base.Creator.create(Creator.java:45)
    at com.twilio.notifications.config.TestMain.main(TestMain.java:18)
```

Comment: please describe the issue and list the steps that cause it and what you have done to try to fix.

Comment: I was trying to run the basic send SMS code.. i was getting the issue.. i couldn't understand much on the error to fix it..

Comment: please update your question text

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well when trying out the quick start example. I verified that I had the correct verified phone numbers, the text did not have an empty message and the code specified the to and from numbers properly.

I found the issue to be proxy related. Once fixed this in my local setup, it worked like a charm. It also worked without any issues in the server.

Hope this helps,

Alice